# Declaring scanner to read system.in

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, system.in

Looking at Java tutorials, it seems you have to wrap up multiple layers of objects when declaring a scanner e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

```
s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("xanadu.txt")));
```

has both `BufferedReader` and `FileReader`. However, if I'm reading from `System.in` do I need to / is there any benefit to doing this? Do the two options behave differently?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in)));
```

vs

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
```

Comment: While buffering might help with large files, I do not see any advantage in using it with keyboard input (`System.in`). And just to prevent future problems, when opening a `Scanner` for `System.in`, either close it at the very end of your code (after everything has been read) or do not close at all.

Comment: `System.in` can come from a file too using redirection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difference is in the efficiency. If used properly  `BufferedReader` prevents bytes that are read from file to be converted into characters and then returned back. So using `BufferedReader` is recommended.

Additionally, you can specify buffer size, that is very handy.

Answer (score 1):

The buffering part is definitely different. Please read more about IO buffering here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/buffers.html